# Service Broker Enable Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to publish my web application (ASP.NET MVC) to Azure.

When I developed the system locally I used SQL Server as the database server.

Here I'm trying to use Azure SQL.

I want to enable Service Broker on the Azure database but it won't let me do it. I got an error that.

> The operation cannot be performed on database "dbrngls" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability group.

Is there any other way to do this in Azure SQL?

This is the code I tried to do to enable Broker

```
ALTER DATABASE [dbrngls] SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service broker is not available for Azure SQL Database, you'd need an Azure SQL Managed Instance.

Comment: Or SQL on a VM, IaaS.

Comment: Is Service Broker available in Azure SQL Managed Instance?

Comment: I believe so @bjnr